# How to escape escaped quote in bash

Tags: python, bash, sh

I try to run python code with "c" parameter:

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(1): print(\'rob\')'
```

It's worked, prints

```
rob
```

But i want to print quote:

```
I'm a rob
```

This not worked of course:

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(10): print(\'I'm rob\')'
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you write that string in Python? If you wanted to keep it in single quotes, it would be something like:

```
print('I\'m rob')
```

...so that would become, inside a `$''`-quoted string, something like:

```
print(\'I\\\'m rob\')
```

...once you escape both the quotes *and the literal backslash* parsed by the Python interpreter as protection for the internal quote. Thus:

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(10): print(\'I\\\'m rob\')'
```

---

By the way -- there's no good reason to do this by hand when you can ask the shell to do it for you:

```
script=$(cat <<'EOF'
import sys
for r in range(10):
  print('I\'m rob')
EOF
)

printf '%q ' python3 -c "$script"; printf '\n'
```

...emits:

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(10):\n  print(\'I\\\'m rob\')'
```

...which you can actually run as code. (Or you could just run `python3 -c "$script"` after the above heredoc-based definition, which will invoke your script without ever needing to involve a hand-escaped copy of the code anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Using escaped double quotes in the `print` should work:

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(10): print(\"I\'m rob\")'
```

Comment: Yes. But this solution force me to use double quotes.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because I already have some python code, and not able to edit it

Comment: Please include these sorts of things into your future questions. Also this is only part of the answer we're looking for anyways. What exactly do you mean by "some python code" and the fact that you cannot edit it?

Answer (score 0):

As per @pault said but with further  explanation.

This isn't working because you're ending the string and starting over by putting the quotes in, that's because you used a single quote to denounce the string. This can be easily remedied by using double quotes to denounce the string.

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(10): print("I\'m rob")'
```

Comment: Why escape the double quotes when they're inside ANSI-C-style quoting? `echo $'"'` emits `"` without needing to make it `$'\"'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using any other arguments for the Python script, pass the string as an argument to reduce the amount of nested quoting you need.

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nfor r in range(1): print(sys.argv[1])' "I'm a rob"
```